# Solving for x=2 fails when using Z3.Monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, z3

I'm trying to do a really basic example using Z3.Monad interface in Haskell. Unfortunately the package doesn't list a simple, working example so I'm starting from scratch. I have also checked and the examples listed in the package work for me, so there should be no underlying issue with my Z3 installation.

**What am I doing**

This is the function that fails when run it:

```
import Z3.Monad

computeTwo = evalZ3 $ do
    x <- mkFreshIntVar "x"
    _2 <- mkInteger 2
    assert =<< mkEq x _2
    fmap snd $ withModel $ \m -> fromJust <$> evalInt m x
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
uncaught exception: ErrorCall
Z3.Base.toBool: illegal `Z3_bool' value
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Z3/Base.hs:3197:23 in z3-4.3.1- 
JxhFvE2Tmnm1VKrfgyob6s:Z3.Base
```

**What answer was expected**

The model should check with x=2.

**What other things I've tried**

The equivalent example works in the [Z3 online checker](https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial)

```
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (= x 2))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Producing the answer:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun x () Int
    2)
)
```

Comment: I just pasted your file and then ran `print =<< computeTwo` in both ghci and compiled and they both produced `Just 2`.  So there is something going on with your environment.

Comment: Thanks @luqui - very good to know.

Comment: I too have no problem running this code.  Using Z3 4.8, GHC 8.4.3, OS-X. EDIT: and the Haskell z3 bindings version 4.3.1

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson - would you be able to elaborate how you installed Z3 on OS X and linked it (in stack?)? I tried installing from source and from homebrew and neither version works for me.

Comment: Z3 is a separate program and library, written in C++.  The Haskell package is simply a binding to the library - or perhaps it calls out to the executabe but I don't think so.  You can download Z3 from github and build it locally for best results (i.e. in the past the latest released Z3 was still a bit old) or you can download a released binary.

Comment: That is to say, I installed [z3 from source](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), performed `cabal update ; cabal install z3` to get the Haskell bindings, pasted your code into a new `foo.hs` file, fixed it by adding `import Data.Maybe`, then loaded it in GHCi and ran `computeTwo` to obtain the result.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson that's exactly what I've done. I've both installed it from brew via `brew install z3` in `usr/local/Cellar/z3/4.7.1` and also installed it from GitHub into `usr/local/bin`. Which approach did you follow and how did you point the z3 bindings? I used a `stack.yaml` file for that.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson thank you!

Comment: You might be also interested in `sbv` package - a more high level interface to different solvers, including Z3.

Comment: The package provides several small examples, see https://github.com/IagoAbal/haskell-z3/tree/master/examples. If you read the package description, or the README, both link to these examples. You are welcome to contribute other examples.

Comment: @iago - yeah I was using these but they ran successfully for me so I was looking for an absolute minimal example.

Comment: @iago I'd love to add my super simple example if it makes sense as a starting point :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by:

**1) Updating XCode**

Using the App Store.

**2) Reinstalling z3**

```
 brew uninstall z3
 brew install z3
 echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
 echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"' >> ~/.bash_profile
 echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Last three were specific instructions from the `brew install` process.

Thanks all for your help.